# error: expected expression before 'else'

Tags: objective-c

I am making a button that pauses and plays a sound. Here is my coding:

.h:

```
@interface RootViewController : UIViewController {
} 
@property (nonatomic, retain) AVAudioPlayer *theAudio;
-(IBAction)pause;

@end
```

.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MathMusic1" ofType:@"wav"];
    self.theAudio = [[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL] autorelease];
    theAudio.delegate = self;
    [theAudio play];
    theAudio.numberOfLoops = -1;

    [super viewDidLoad];


}
```

Now i am trying to make a button to pause this so here is that coding: (Already declared in .h)

```
-(IBAction)pause {

    [theAudio pause];




    else // expected expression before 'else'
    [theAudio play];

}
```

/ error: expected expression before 'else'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an `else` without an `if` (just before), I think it may be the error in your code.

Answer (score 0):

you don't have an `if` statement.