# Making a button play and pause background sound

Tags: objective-c, audio

I have errors with my code:

```
-(IBAction)pause {
    [theAudio pause];

    if [theAudio pause] {
    else {
        [theAudio play];
    }
}
}
```

I am very new to c and xcode and I am really not sure what to do. Please provide the right code in relation to this.

Comment: Uh, you probably need to make a LITTLE effort if you want help.  Like telling us what the errors are, what you're trying to accomplish and that "theAudio" is.  Programming is about you figuring out problems, not having people "provide the right code."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted has some syntax errors, it should look like the following:

```
-(IBAction)pause {      
    if ([theAudio isPaused]) {
        [theAudio play];
    } else {
        [theAudio pause];
    }
}
```

I have no idea if your `theAudio` object has an `isPaused` method, basically in the if statement you should be checking whether the audio is playing or not, and use that to set the audio to play or pause.

Answer (score 2):

i suggest you team up with user 722566, and work through problems *together*:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838749/error-expected-before-token-and-expected-declaration-or-statement-at-end

[Making a button play and pause background sound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838829/making-a-button-play-and-pause-background-sound)

[error: expected expression before 'else'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838668/xcode-error-expected-expression-before-else)

it seems like you two have a lot of identical questions, at approximately the same time.

thanks